# Im having trouble with this code in python

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
def create_dict(my_file):
    my_lines = my_file.readlines()   
    my_dict = {}

    for line in my_lines:
         items = line.split()
         key, values = items[0], items[2:3] + items[1:2] + items[5:6] +items[3:4] + items[4:5]
         my_dict[key] = values

    return my_dict
```

I need it to return

```
{
  'asmith': ['Smith', 'Alice', 'alice.smith@utsc.utoronto.ca', 31, 'F'], 
  'rford': ['Ford', 'Rob', 'robford@crackshack.com', 44, 'M'] 
 }
```

But its returning:

```
{
   'asmith': ['Smith', 'Alice', 'alice.smith@utsc.utoronto.ca', '31', 'F'], 

    'rford': ['Ford', 'Rob', 'robford@crackshack.com', '44', 'M']. 
 }
```

I need to change the age values into integers and i've tried using `int(items[3:4])`, but it says that the object has to be a string to be converted into an integer. Can anyone seem to find out why its doing this?

Comment: The line you want is:
 `key, values = items[0], [items[2], items[1], items[5], int(items[3]), items[4]]`

Comment: Thank you Evan! It seemed to work, I guess that not putting the values into a list caused this problem. It sees to work now thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int("".join(items[3:4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `int(''.join(item))`. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `int(my_dict['asmith'][3])`

`items[3:4]` returns a list which cannot be turned into an integer. `items[3]` appears to be the location of age.

Answer (score 0):

say your `my_file` has two lines like following:

```
asmith Smith Alice alice.smith@utsc.utoronto.ca  31 F       
rford Ford Rob robford@crackshack.com  44 M
```

and you can use this:

```
def create_dict(my_file):
    my_dict = {}
    with open(my_file, 'r') as f:  # close file without do it by yourself
        for line in f:  # it works even though the file has large size
            items = line.split()
            items[4] = int(items[4])  # convert age type from str to int
            my_dict[items[0]] = items[1:]
    return my_dict
```

test:

```
>>> create_dict('/home/mingxian/Desktop/pythontest/testfile')
{'rford': ['Ford', 'Rob', 'robford@crackshack.com', 44, 'M'], 'asmith': ['Smith', 'Alice', 'alice.smith@utsc.utoronto.ca', 31, 'F']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Oh ok im new to stackoverflow so I'll learn this stuff soon :)